# Minimum circles to cover a set of points and avoid another set of points

Tags: algorithms, optimization, computational-geometry

Points are in 2d euclidean space. Given a set of n points, A, and a set of m points, B, what is the minimally sized set of circles such that this set of circles covers all points in A and no point in B is covered by a circle?

circles can have arbitrary radius

any thoughts about the difficulty of this problem? any thoughts on non trivial exact algorithms?

Comment: I think this is a set-cover problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem  So it probably will be a NP complete task requiring use of some approximation algorithm rather than finding exact solution in practical world. Hope I am not totally wrong :-)

Comment: @Firzen not exactly the same, but it looks like close enough to make me suspect it is NP-hard.

Answer (score 3):

The following algorithm will find *some* set of circles, containing all the points in the set $A$ except all the points in the set $B$. This solution might be not optimal (please see the @j_random_hacker counterexample in comments), and it's unclear how close this solution will be to the optimal one. The time complexity of this algorithm is exponential, cause it needs the [Set Cover Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) solution as one of its steps.

**Step 1.** Build [Voronoi Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of the set $B$. This diagram will consist of *cells*, *nodes*, *line segments* and *rays*. Each node will correspond to (at least) three points from the set $B$, and each ray will correspond to exactly two points from the set $B$.

**Step 2.** For each Voronoi node construct a **maximal empty open disk** with center in this node. These disks will have (at least) three points from the set $B$ on their boundary, and they won't contain any points from the set $B$. The number of such disks will be $\Theta(|B|)$.

**Step 3.** For each Voronoi ray construct a **maximal empty open disk** with center at this ray and infinitely large radius - it'll be actually a *halfplane*, corresponding to two points from the *convex hull* of the set $B$. These "disks" will have exactly two points from the set $B$ on their boundary, and they won't contain any points from the set $B$. The number of such "disks" will be $\Theta(|B|)$.

**Step 4.** For each point from the set $A$ find all disks, constructed above, containing this point. Each such point may belong to more than one disk, and each disk may contain any number of points from zero to $|A|$. Find a **minimal subset** of the set of all disks, which contains all the points from the set $A$. This is the classic [Set Cover Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), which is NP-complete (it's tempting to try to use geometric nature of this sub-problem to accelerate the search, however it won't be possible - please see the [Geometric Set Cover Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_set_cover_problem) page for more details).

---

I'm thankful to @DiscreteLizard for pointing my error out in the previous version of this answer, and for suggesting the term "disk", which looks more adequate than the "circle".

---

I'd call this problem a "Bomber Problem" - we try to use a minimal number of bombs to strike all needed locations except some friendly ones. Sorry for militaristic jargon!

Comment: I like the Voronoi diagram idea and think this is sufficient to avoid any "gaps" where $A$-points could be hiding, but this doesn't necessarily produce optimal solutions. See e.g. https://imgur.com/MZsEf09, where black points are in $A$ and red points are in $B$: The solid red disks in the image on the left shows the 3-disk solution you would find, while the solid disks in the right show an optimal 2-disk solution.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - thank you! Your example shows that my approach is too rigid

Comment: @j_random_hacker - also your example shows that my disks might not completely cover my universe, oops! I'll need to make corrections...

Comment: I came to the conclusion that the disks your method creates *do* cover every $A$-point, which is all you need to ensure that you can always find a solution (if not necessarily an optimal one). The Delaunay triangulation corresponding to the Voronoi diagram already covers (in fact, partitions) the space inside "landlocked" (finite-size) Voronoi cells with triangles, and every such triangle is completely inside a disk that your algorithm creates, so the disks definitely cover all of this area. And I think $A$-points lying in infinite-size Voronoi cells are also covered by some circle.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - sorry to say, no... If radii of external disks aren't that large, then there will be areas, not covered by them. However I know, how to fix that

Answer (score 3):

If $B$ is empty, just pick a single circle. Otherwise, here's a way to turn this continuous problem into a discrete (but still probably hard) problem:

**Lemma:** There exists an optimal solution in which every circle falls into one of the following cases:

1. It has diameter zero and is centred on an $A$-point.
2. It has at least 2 $A$-points on its boundary, and some $B$-point a very small distance $\epsilon > 0$ from its boundary.
3. It has at least 3 $A$-points on its boundary.

**Proof sketch:** Suppose we have an optimal solution. For any circle with no $A$-points on its boundary, shrink it (keeping the centre in the same position) until it does: Notice that shrinking never causes a point that was outside the circle to move inside it, so this never causes a $B$-point to become covered. Do this for all circles, until all circles have at least one $A$-point on their boundary. If that is the only $A$-point in the circle, shrink that circle all the way down to diameter 0 and centre it at that point.

Second, for any circle that has only one $A$-point on its boundary but at least one other $A$-point inside it, "pull-shrink" it towards the boundary point until at least one more $A$-point lies on its boundary. By "pull-shrink" I mean: Keep that boundary $A$-point on the boundary, and move the circle centre some distance $x$ along the straight line towards it, thereby also reducing the circle's radius by $x$. Pull-shrinking also never causes a point that was outside the circle to move inside it. Think of lying a cylinder on the ground so that it could roll, and putting a smaller-diameter cylinder inside it: the smaller cylinder lies completely inside the larger one, touching it only at the very bottom point.

Finally, "puff out" each circle until either an $A$-point inside it almost escapes (lies on the boundary), or a $B$-point outside it almost touches the boundary, whichever happens first. By "puff out" I mean: Keep the 2 boundary $A$-points on the boundary, and move the circle centre away from them along their perpendicular bisector, causing it to enlarge. Unlike shrinking and pull-shrinking, puffing out can cause points that were inside the circle to move outside, and vice versa. That's why we need a more flexible stopping condition. (For this process to terminate, it may actually be necessary to move the circle centre in the opposite direction, which initially shrinks it: This is necessary if there are no $B$-points in the half-plane defined by the line connecting the  two boundary $A$-points and containing the circle centre. Since we have assumed $|B| \ge 1$, at least one of the two half-planes contains a $B$-point, so at least one of the two movement directions will cause the circle to eventually get within $\epsilon$ of a $B$-point, which is all that matters for this proof.)

Starting from an arbitrary optimal solution, after performing these steps, we have constructed a same-size (i.e., optimal) solution that still covers all $A$-points, avoids all $B$-points, and in which each circle either has diameter zero, or has at least 2 $A$-points on its boundary, in addition to either a third boundary $A$-point or a $B$-point just outside its boundary. What this means is that it suffices to consider *only* solutions in which each circle has this property.

---

Since **any 3 non-collinear points lie on the boundary of exactly 1 circle**, we need only consider a finite-size set of circles to choose from:

1. The $|A|$ diameter-0 circles centred on $A$-points.
2. The at most $|B|{|A| \choose 2}$ circles formed by choosing any 2 $A$-points and any $B$-point, which are not collinear, to lie on its boundary, excluding those that contain a $B$-point.
3. The at most $|A| \choose 3$ circles formed by choosing any 3 non-collinear $A$-points to lie on its boundary, excluding those that contain a $B$-point.

Of course, you can also get rid of any circle whose $A$-points are completely contained by some other valid circle, and doing so should speed things up.

To solve the problem, generate these $O(n^3)$ circles and solve a [Set Cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) in which the set of items to be covered is $A$, and each circle contributes a set, namely the set of $A$-points that it covers.

It may be that the Euclidean structure in the problem means that some asymptotically faster algorithm can be used than a general Set Cover solver.

Answer (score 2):

The following randomized incremental algorithm finds a set of disks, containing all the points from the set $A$ except all the points from the set $B$, in polynomial time. It's unclear, how close this set of disks will be to the optimal solution.

The algorithm maintains a disk set, containing a subset of the set $A$ and not containing any points from the set $B$. Points from the set $A$ are inserted
into the disk set one by one. The disk set can change at each step. The algorithm ends after all the points from the set $A$ are inserted into the disk set.

**Step 1.** Randomly choose a point $p_1 \in A$ and create a disk $D_1$ with center in the point $p_1$ and zero radius. Create a disk set $S=\{D_1\}$.

**Step $i$ for $i \gt 1$.** The previously constructed disk set $S=\{D_1,\dots,D_k\}$ contains points $\{p_1,\dots,p_{i-1}\} \subset A$ and doesn't contain any points from the set $B$. Randomly choose a point $p_i \in A \setminus \{p_1,\dots,p_{i-1}\}$ and perform following operations.

- If the point $p_i$ is contained in some disk from the set $S$, then this set isn't changed - step $i$ is done.
- Otherwise randomly scan disks from the set $S$ trying to find an *expandable disk* - a disk $D$, which can be expanded to contain all the points it contained previously *plus* the new point $p_i$. This expanded disk can be constructed easily, however to be *expandable* it must meet additional condition - **this disk must not contain any points from the set $B$**.
- If such expandable disk $D^*$ is found, replace the disk $D$ by the disk $D^*$ in the set $S$ - step $i$ is done. If an expandable disk is not found, create a new disk with center in the point $p_i$ and zero radius. Add this disk to the set $S$.

Each step of this algorithm will need to scan at most $n$ disks, and for each expanded disk - verify its intersection with all the $m$ points from the set $B$. So, the running time of this algorithm is obviously $O(n^2m)$. This estimate can be improved using more sophisticated data structures for sets $S$ and $B$.

The algorithm can be generalized to work with any types of obstacles instead of isolated points - segments, polygons etc.